# No route found for "GET /" in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I just installed symfony. To install it I used this:

```
php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony.phar
php symfony.phar
php symfony.phar new myrest
```

And in CMD I had written:

> Run your application:
>
> 1. Execute the php app/console server:run command.
> 2. Browse to the http://localhost:8000 URL.

So I browsed it but I have an error:

```
 No route found for "GET /"
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception:
ResourceNotFoundException »
[2/2] NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /"
[1/2] ResourceNotFoundException: 
error

    ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /"" at C:\xampp\htdocs\test\myrest\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php line 159
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
    DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
```

Somebody know what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. This is because in Symfony 2.7 is not AcmeDemoBundle. There is only one controller under /app/example url. Nothing more. I suggest installing  [Symfony Demo application](http://symfony.com/blog/introducing-the-symfony-demo-application). It is working example of app built with Symfony (with GET / defined).

```
php symfony.phar demo
```

So, this error is not a real error or Symfony problem. It's a lack of your app code.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/758#issuecomment-70380908

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it is actually working, listening to the / route, and you just don't have any controller defined for that route.

You should probably create a new bundle and edit the routing.yml file automatically NewBundle/Resources/config/ to match that route.

To create a bundle, run:

> php app/console generate:bundle

And follow the instructions.

Something like

```
homepage:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: NewBundle:Default:index }
```

Replacing YourNewBundle with the name of the bundle you just created.

You can get more info at 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html